# ng-click won't work with dynamic includes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-include

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bf8m/21/) demonstrates some code where I lazily add a partial with it's own controller.

Everything works fine, but for some reason my `ng-click` event just won't fire. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the "()" in the ng-click

```
'<button ng-click="onClick()">Click</button>' +
```

See : http://jsfiddle.net/8Bf8m/22/